# Expected value of $X$ when an unbiased coin is tossed $5$ times

Tags: probability

> An unbiased coin is tossed $5$ times. Suppose that a variable $X$ is assigned the value $k$ when $k$
>   consecutive heads are obtained for $k = 3, 4, 5$ otherwise $X$ takes the value $–1$. Then the expected value of $X$, is :

For $k=0, X=-1, P(X)={5\choose0}(\frac12)^5$

$k=1, X=-1, P(X)={5\choose1}(\frac12)^5$

$k=2, X=-1, P(X)={5\choose2}(\frac12)^5$

$k=3, X=3, P(X)={5\choose3}(\frac12)^5$

$k=4, X=4, P(X)={5\choose4}(\frac12)^5$

$k=5, X=5, P(X)={5\choose5}(\frac12)^5$

So, Expected value $E(X)=(-1\cdot1+-1\cdot5+-1\cdot10+3\cdot10+4\cdot5+5\cdot1)(\frac1{32})=\frac{39}{32}$

The answer is given as $\frac18$.

Comment: The reason for downvote please?

Comment: consecutive....

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I can now see that we need consecutive heads. And I am just calculating for number of heads. But not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Four consecutive heads is: HHHHT or THHHH; three consecutive heads is: HHHTH, HHHTT, THHHT, TTHHH, or HTHHH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve counted the number of ways to get $k$ heads, but what’s needed for each $k$ is the number of ways to get $k$ **consecutive** heads. For example, there are just $5$ ways to get $3$ consecutive heads, not $10$: HHHTT, HHHTH, THHHT, TTHHH, and HTHHH. There are just $2$ ways to get $4$ consecutive heads: HHHHT and THHHH. And there is one way to get $5$ consecutive heads. Each of the other $2^5-(5+2+1)=24$ outcomes results in a score of $-1$, so

$$E(X)=\frac{5\cdot3+2\cdot4+1\cdot5-24}{32}=\frac4{32}=\frac18\;.$$

This problem is small enough that it really is easiest simply to list the possibilities.